# How can I setup my Mac so fsck only runs at night?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

Every so often, my Mac kicks off **fsck_hfs** and as I sit here working I have to listen to the hard drive thrash for an hour or two as well as put up with some performance hits.

Is there any way to configure OS X such that **fsck** will run at a specific time (say 3am while I'm sleeping)?

Comment: man 3am is prime work time... its clear you simply need to reconfigure your work habits. ;-)

Comment: Why are there votes to close? Is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: Its more geared towards SuperUser than stackoverflow. All votes thus far have been for offtopic:superuser so if/when the question is closed there is a good chance it will be migrated there.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with that site. I'll take a look.